# Where can I find tutorials or webcasts for doing Sharepoint development?

Tags: sharepoint

Where can I find tutorials or webcasts for doing Sharepoint development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [www.dotnetrocks.com](http://www.dotnetrocks.com) and [www.dnrtv.com](http://www.dnrtv.com)

Specifically :-

- [Ted Pattison Shows us Sharepoint](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=189)
- [Sahil Malik on Sharepoint 2007 Part 1](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=43)
- [Sahil Malik on Sharepoint 2007 Part 2](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=48)
- [Sahil Malik on Sharepoint 2007 Part 3](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=55)
- [Sahil Malik on Sharepoint 2007 Part 4](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=62)

Answer (score 0):

great for starters:-

http://www.microsoft.com/click/SharePointDeveloper/

Lots of cool stuff on here too:-

http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [free tutorials](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-hosting/free-sharepoint-tutorials.asp) about sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

[Robert Shelton](http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/04/series-of-sharepoint-workflow-how-to-videos.aspx) has an excellent series of videos on Workflow development on his blog, as well as [downloadable .pdf tutorials](http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/sharepoint-document-workflow-with-visual-studio-workshop-documents-download.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Robert Bogue and Andrew Connell made a really good [web cast series](http://blogs.msdn.com/emre/archive/2008/05/24/sharepoint-development-webcast-for-net-developers.aspx) for Microsoft and it sure was a good primer for me.

If you like pod casts I can recomment [the SharePoint pod show](http://www.sharepointpodshow.com/) which will keep you updated about all things SharePoint :-)

I you are a true TDD believer like me then [Andrew Woodward](http://www.21apps.com/sharepoint/tdd-at-spbpc-slidedeck/) is the place to go.